# How do I pass the detailed error message thrown in the node sails backend to a fetch request while calling only one method of the node res object?

Tags: node.js, exception, fetch, sails.js

I've been trying to get both the status code and the detailed error message that is passed by the sails model function "findOneOrCreate," which throws the error below when the query object doesn't conform to the model's schema

```
{
    code: 'E_INVALID_NEW_RECORD',
    details: 'Missing value for required attribute `first_opened_app_at`.  Expected a value, but instead, got: undefined',
    modelIdentity: 'device'
  },
  isOperational: true,
  code: 'E_INVALID_NEW_RECORD',
  details: 'Missing value for required attribute `first_opened_app_at`.  Expected a value, but instead, got: undefined',
  modelIdentity: 'device'
}
```

which is thrown in the first catch block in the sails controller method below:

```
    logDevice: async function (req, res) {

        const deviceId = req.params.deviceId
        const deviceType = req.params.deviceType

        Device.findOrCreate({ device_id: deviceId}, { device_id: deviceId, device_type: deviceType })
        .then((err, device, wasCreated) => {
          if(wasCreated) {
            console.log('Logged a new device: ' + device.device_id + "("+device.device_type+")" );
            res.send({ 'wasCreated': wasCreated})
          }
          else {
            console.log('Found an existing device: ' + device.device_id + "("+device.device_type+")");
            res.send({ 'wasCreated' : wasCreated })
          }
        })
        // Some other kind of usage / validation error
        .catch({ name: 'UsageError' }, err => {
            console.log(err)
          return res.badRequest(err);
        })
        // Adaptor error
        .catch({ name: 'AdapterError' }, err => {
            console.log(err)
          res.badRequest(err);
        })
        // If something completely unexpected happened.
        .catch(err => {
          res.serverError(err);
        });
    },
```

The method that I'm using to pass the err object with the detailed error message back is the `badrequest` method. I'd like to keep using this method because it accurately describes the actual problem, as the request parameters provided aren't conforming to the model's schema.

But when I pass the err object into `badRequest` as below:

```
res.badRequest(err)
```

I'm not getting the detailed error in JSON format (in the first of the formatted code blocks in this question)

I know that if I do

```
res.send({err: err})
```

or something along those lines, I'll get the error message, but then I won't get the status codes and other useful info that I'm getting when I'm calling `badRequest` which are below:

```
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {map: {…}}
ok: false
status: 400
statusText: ""
type: "default"
url: "http://192.168.1.76:1337/devices/logDevice/949235da12ba6ee5/android"
_bodyBlob: Blob {_data: {…}}
_bodyInit: Blob {_data: {…}}
```

What's the "right" way or a good way for me to get all of the above info - both the detailed error messages and the info I'm getting with badRequest so that in my front end the response variable has all this info inside it while preferably calling a single method attached to the res object? I know I can just merge the two objects or do something like that but I want the code to be "nice" since I'll have to do something similar in a lot of different places.

```
  fetch(global.BASE_URL+'/devices/logDevice/'+DeviceInfo.getUniqueId()+'/'+Platform.OS, {
    method: "get"
  })
  .then( response => {
    if (response.ok) {

      return response.json()
    }
    console.log(response)
    throw new Error(response);
  })
  .then( data => {
      console.log(data)
  })
  .catch( err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> the first of the formatted code blocks in this question

is not a valid JSON

You need to send a valid JSON to the method:

Like the other [built-in](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/response-res/res-bad-request) custom response modules, the behaviour of this method is customizable.

By default, it works as follows:

- The status code of the response is set to 400.
- Sails sends any provided error data as JSON. If no data is provided,
  a default response body will be sent (the string "Bad Request").

You can make these changes in the catch block, make a valid JSON to pass it to `badRequest` method.

```
 const error = {
     detail: err.details,
     code: err.code
 }
 return res.badRequest(error);
```